# Unable to authenticate Proxy using quarkus-microprofile restclient

Tags: microprofile, quarkus-rest-client, proxy-authentication, eclipse-microprofile-config

Any ideas on why `quarkus-microprofile rest-client` (version 1.3) ignores System-env properties proxy username and proxy password. It definitely considers using the proxy host and port as I am getting an HTTP-407 from the proxy server.

https.proxyHost and https.proxyPort are considered but NOT https.proxyUser and https.proxyPassword.

Do we need to set an Authenticator somehow?

Strangely, other clients implemented in the same project(for example: google HTTP client) successfully connects to the Proxy server.

Comment: can you try a newer version of Quarkus? Also, with `quarkus-rest-client-reactive`?

Comment: @MichałSzynkiewicz  Since it was an urgent issue, i implemented a new java11 HTTP Client and got it working.  But as far as i see the client implementation from resteasy it is somehow  considering only the proxy host and port . But thanks for the suggestion, i will check the quarkus-rest-client-reactive client implementation too.